# Using HTML to display the different icon sizes in a .ico file on a webpage

Tags: html, icons

I'm trying to display the different sized icons in a .ico file on a webpage.  Using HTML img tags results in showing the smallest (first icon in the .ico file, really) icon.

Is it possible to display the other icons from the .ico file? Or is the .ico format deemed too specific to Windows, and thus not supported by HTML/browsers?

Going by some related questions here and elsewhere, where people have to parse the contents of the .ico file, in e.g. C#, I'm guessing this not possible.

I can of course pull the individual icons out of the .ico file and save them separately, but I'm curious if there's a way to use the existing file in this case.

(Just-in-case disclaimer: I am not talking about favicons; I'm displaying the icon on a webpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that in HTML.

What you can do is use a scripting langage, such as PHP, to read the .ico and output the different images it stores into different converted images.

If you want to do this in PHP, take a look at [this page](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2369-PHP-Extract-graphics-from-ico-files-into-PNG-images.html)

Comment: Thanks for the example and answer.